# Ajax event does not fire on JSF page when an item is selected (update)

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I am learning JavaEE and I am playing around with ajax call with jsf and managedbean. I am trying to display the text as soon as i change the value from the drop down list. I see many people have the same problem on stackoverflow and i try to follow answers that are marked as accepted but I still can't make it work. Can someone please tell me where my error is? 
Here is the jsf code:

```
<h:form> 
        <h:selectOneMenu id="productlist" value="#{productRepoMB.selectedProduct}">       
            <f:selectItems value="#{productRepoMB.productList}" var="product" itemValue="#{product.productID}" />          
            <f:ajax event="valueChange"
                    render="result"
                    listener="#{productRepoMB.selectMenuListener}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
       text changed: <h:outputText id="result" value="#{productRepoMB.text}" />        
</h:form>
```

Here is managed bean code, Products list is populated from a database:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ProductRepoMB implements Serializable {
@EJB
private ProductsRepo productRepo;

private Products selectedProduct;
private List<Products> productList;

private String text="init text"; //use for testing ajax call

public ProductRepoMB() {
}

public Products getSelectedProduct() {
    return selectedProduct;
}

public List<Products> getProductList() {
    productList = productRepo.findAll();
    return productList;
}

//The following code are used to testing ajax only!
public void selectMenuListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
    setText("changed!");
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text){
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

Comment: is your function getSelectMenuListener() called?

Comment: yes, if i place getSelectMenuListener() inside getProductList() for testing, the output text does display "changed!"

Comment: change the name of the function in selectMenuListener()

Comment: I just changed method name. It still does not work.

Comment: Make an ajax function: selectMenuListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent e)

Comment: or try another event event="valueChange"

Comment: I tried both of them. Still not working

Comment: You're actually missing a setter for the selected product. This code won't work without that. Event has not to be set explicitly when ajax used into a `h:selectOneMenu`. You can write it as `<f:ajax
                    render="result"
                    listener="#{productRepoMB.selectMenuListener}" />`. Also check the `equals()` implementations for your `Products` entity, they may not work properly.

Comment: go through: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html

Comment: I added attribute immediate=true and it fixed my problem. It's strange since some people say immediate is not neccessary.